# CKEDITOR Duplicate modules

Tags: angular, ckeditor

Angular 12

I have followed the various suggestions in resolving this issue without success.

I have found that compiling in development mode I do not get the error but when I compile in production mode I do get the error.

My configurations from angular.json

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "4mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": ""
    }
```

package.json

`"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.2", "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^29.2.0",`

app.modules.ts

`import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';`

mycomponent.ts

`import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: share the error logs ?

Comment: This is what I see in the console:

Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    i ckeditor.js:5
    exports ckeditor.js:5
    exports ckeditor.js:5
    n ckeditor.js:5
    exports ckeditor.js:5
    n ckeditor.js:5
    exports ckeditor.js:5
    6701 ckeditor.js:5